# time data '2022-01-07T02:05:1' does not match fotmat '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime, valueerror, strptime

I have some unpredicted errors with a date string. I have a try/except to navigate through it at it worked for a while, but now I'm running into this.

Here is my current code:

```
def parse_date(date_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    except ValueError:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I the except I tried to have another try/except for certain format to account for lack of zero-padding, such as this:

```
def parse_date(date_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    except ValueError:
            try:
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            except:
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%-S")
```

No luck so far. Any suggestion where i could go from here?

Comment: There's a `T` missing in the format string from the error message. Why? And show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the Z at the end and it should work.

```
def parse_date(date_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```